# Multiple vote casting prevention code lets users vote twice

Tags: php

I have a upvote button and a downvote button and I'm trying to use a cookie to prevent the same user from voting after they've voted already, but my code lets them vote exactly twice before graying-out the vote buttons.  What's wrong with my code?

```
<html>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"/>
<input id="upvote" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upvote" 
    <?php 
    if (isset($_COOKIE['chocolatechip']) and $_COOKIE['chocolatechip'] = 
"voted=1") 
        {
        echo "disabled";
        } 
    ?>>
<input id="downvote" type="submit" name="submit" value="Downvote"
    <?php 
    if (isset($_COOKIE['chocolatechip']) and $_COOKIE['chocolatechip'] = 
"voted=1") 
        {
        echo "disabled";
        } 
    ?>>
</form>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Upvote") // if upvoted clicked
    {
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE object_votes_table SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 
WHERE object = 'Ceramic'");
    setcookie('chocolatechip', 'voted=1');
    }
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Downvote") // if downvoted clicked
    {
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE object_votes_table SET downvotes = downvotes 
+ 1 WHERE object = 'Ceramic'");
    setcookie('chocolatechip', 'voted=1');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're **assigning** the value here `$_COOKIE['chocolatechip'] = 
"voted=1"` instead of **comparing**. Add one more **=** and you should be ok.

Comment: The comparison operator issue aside, you got to keep in mind that you can only read cookies from $_COOKIE with the _next_ requests, not directly inside the script instance where you are _setting_ them. So first of all you should turn your logic around - process the form data first, output form after, so that you can set the disabled attribute on the buttons already, after you just processed a vote successfully.

Comment: Plus you need to be aware of course, that a disabled button won’t mean no one can send such requests to your script any more. So you should at least check for the cookie before you add another vote to the database ...

Comment: Okay, I did what you said.  I put the database vote increment code and set cookie code above the html form code, but it didn't change anything.  Neither did changing = to ==.  I did try putting a cookie check before incrementing any values in the database, and that prevents two votes from the same user getting registered in the database, but they can still click the button twice before it grays out.  Purely for aesthetic reasons I'd like to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

...`and $_COOKIE['chocolatechip'] == "voted=1"`

instead of

...`and $_COOKIE['chocolatechip'] = "voted=1"`

I have no explanation why your code works after the *second* time, but hopefully this helps...